# Cosmos Db Throughput

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there any option to retrieve Cosmos DB (SQL API) throughput programmatically. I'm using the below code to get the list of DB

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(ClientURL, ClientKey,);
var databaseList = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().ToList();
```

Next I wanted to know the throughput for each of the database.

Please let me know if this is feasible

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes.. Definitely and Thanks again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to [CreateOfferQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createofferquery?view=azure-dotnet) method to get throughout settings of Database or Collections.

Also,please refer to this rest api:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-an-offer