# Azure Cosmos DB throttle during copying

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have a copy pipeline set up in Azure Data Factory, which copies everything in Cosmos DB daily to Azure Data Lake.
When copying. there is a spike on RU/s. I donot want to increase Throughput.

Anything I can do to lowering the impact? e.g. can I set a limit to the copying pipeline?

[image]

Comment: All operations against your collection consume RU. If you are being throttled, you're going to need more RU. Can you increase RU prior to the copy, perform the copy, and then reduce RU?

Comment: 99% of time RU is very low. Did not find any automatic way to increase RU.

Comment: @Daolin Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @Daolin Hi,any updates now?

Comment: No updates, seems temporary increase RU is the only solution. I'm looking for a way to slow down the copy request.

Answer (score 1):

As @David said in the comment, any interactions with Cosmos DB requires the consumption of Rus. RUs setting is an important indicator of fees and performance. More details, you could refer to this [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units).

Basically, RU metrics will be shocked by the adf copy activity and throughput setting will not be automatically adjusted by cosmos db.

If you do want to adjust throughput setting temporally,you could execute [http trigger azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) with [azure function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure//data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) which is accessed at head and tail of copy activity. In that activity,  adjust throughput settings appropriately with sdk or rest api.(Please refer to the case:[Cosmos Db Throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830016/cosmos-db-throughput/53830754#53830754))

Comment: I'm running a simple adf pipeline for storing data from data lake to cosmos db (sql api).

After setting database throughput to Autopilot 4000 RU/s, the run took ~11 min and I see 207 throttling requests. On setting database throughput to Autopilot 20,000 RU/s, the run took ~7 min and I see 744 throttling requests. Why is that? Thank you!